# What are the patterns of the sequence of polynomials?

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-sequences

In my research, I obtained a sequence of polynomials (I am only able to compute the first 4 of them):
\begin{align}
& f(2) = 1+t, \\
& f(3) = 1+4t+3t^2, \\
& f(4) = 1+6t+12t^2+7t^3, \\
& f(5) = 1+8t+20t^2+28t^3+15t^4.
\end{align}
Is it possible to find the general formula of $f(n)$ using these 4 polynomials? Some patterns are:

1. The constant term is 1.
2. The highest degree term is $(2^{n-1}-1)t^{n-1}$.
3. $(1+t)$ is a factor of each polynomial.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Without definition, your question is meaningless.  The next term, $f(6)$, is obviously $42$.

Comment: @FindStat, thank you very much. The coefficient of $t^2$ in $f(6)$ is 42?

Comment: I don't know - I was joking.  The serious point is that asking for the next term without definition of the sequence is meaningless.

Comment: You need to explain how you got the first four polynomials in order for anyone to comment on finding the next one.

Comment: I don't think that the question is meaningless. I often try to understand data whose origin is irrelevant.

Comment: @RichardStanley it is not meaningless, it is just too few information (for me) in it to answer.

Comment: With that little data, I would bet on the next one being $1+10t+28t^2+48t^3+60t^4+63t^5$. But this is a rather wild guess.

Comment: @fedia: -1 is not a root of your polynomial. My guess: $(t+1)(63 t^4+61 t^3 +19t^2+9t+1)=63\,{t}^{5}+124\,{t}^{4}+80\,{t}^{3}+28\,{t}^{2}+10\,t+1$

Comment: @RichardStanley: I would guess that the OP is trying to compute homology of some complexes (with Euler characteristic 0). If he said what exactly it is, the suggestions would not be that wild.

Comment: @MarkSapir Of course. I'm an idiot who cannot add correctly, and, I guess, everybody has learned that by now. Should be $31t^5$, not $63t^5$. So, 
$$
1+10t+28t^2+48t^3+60t^4+31t^5=(1+t)(1+9t+19t^2+29t^3+31t^4)
$$  
(we are not up to $63$ yet, only up to $31$!)

Comment: Jianrong, I suspect you meant to add that all polynomial coefficients are (positive?) integers.

Comment: @Todd, thank you very much. Yes, all coefficients are positive integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is

$f(n)=(1+t)\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(2(2^k-1)(n-k-1)+1)t^k \right)$

Comment: This is consistent with fedja's guess. Your guess may be as good as anyone's.